# Sharing UTC time between client and Java back-end

Tags: javascript, utc

I want to convert a data string into a timestamp (which would include the UTC offset of the requesting client) using JavaScript for sending to my server side code and then rebuild it on the server. Can anyone recommend a good format to use which has good Java support?

I want to be able parse this string on the server without having to know what timezone im parsing. Is this possible, does anyone have any good solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass time in long value that is always in utc and you can parse it in javascript as browser timezone